# How can I add this to an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, implementation

I want to add these vehicles to an arraylist but it has to be done by the addVehicle method in the CourierManagementSystemImpl class. I'm not sure how to do it.

**Part of public class CMSTestHarness:**

```
//Arraylist
ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>(); 

// Van(registrationNo, make, model, year, odometer, serviceInterval)
cms.addVehicle(new Van("v1", "Toyota", "Sienna", 1998, 0.0, 500.0));
cms.addVehicle(new Van("v2", "Volkswagen", "Routan S", 2009, 0.0, 1000.0));
```

**Part of CourierMangementSystemImpl class**

```
@Override
    public void addVehicle(Van van) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Comment: **where** is `vehicles` defined in your code structrue? In other class?

Comment: Sorry, but you are not giving enough contest. When that ArrayList only exists in your test class, how is your production code supposed to work with that? Read your question to a friend, and then listen to him for all the reasons he will feel unable to help. And it is the same with the readers here. We don't know your assignment, we don't know the other code you have written... Or how you want to bring these things together.

Comment: Yes in another class

Comment: Why you can't add the `Van`? The code seems OK. Any error message are you getting? What are the constructors of the `Van` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, "vehicles" is the field of CMS object. Pass the parameters to the method addVehicle. And in this example, I used string object instead of Van object for simplicity.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CMS cms = new CMS();
    // * This is Van object.
    cms.addVehicle(new Van("v1", "Toyota", "Sienna", 1998, 0.0, 500.0));
    cms.addVehicle(new Van("v2", "Volkswagen", "Routan S", 2009, 0.0, 1000.0));
    for (String s : cms.getVehicles())
        System.out.println(s);
}

public class CMS {

    private ArrayList<String> vehicles = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getVehicles() {
        return this.vehicles;
    }

    public void addVehicle(String van) {
        vehicles.add(van);
    }

}
```